# Flutter: Loading very large Dart data file blocks app

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, flutter-android

**Background**

I am developing a Flutter app using several sizes of the same font. It does some image manipulation with these fonts.

**Problem**

I am using the pure Dart package `image` https://pub.dev/packages/image.

I pre-calculate the various font sizes to lists like this `List<int>`:

```dart
const _font_size_108 = const 
[80,75,3,4,20,0,0,...
```

About 15 size variations of the same font result in a dart file with a file size of 15 MB.

The moment the app loads this file, the app is blocked for a easily 30 seconds. (Loading these fonts from way smaller FNT files takes about the same time, as the data gets expanded.)

Once loaded, everything works smoothly again.

**Question**

Is there a way to reduce the the time it takes to load this large font file?

Is there a Dart / Flutter technique to handle this situation better?

Should I try a native Android lib?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Did you use `compute` function?

Comment: I think that you should load a single font first and then run your app and then spawn some isolates to load other fonts so that you don't block the ui thread.